# Confused about an Integral equation

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I have this integral equation:

$$\int_0^x 2(1-y)dy= [-(1-y)^2]_0^x$$

I just can't figure out how they got $-(1-y)^2$. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: typo? should be $2y-y^2$

Comment: it was given to us by our prof

Answer (score 1):

write your integral in the form
$$2\int_{0}^xdy-2\int_{0}^xydy=2y|_{0}^x-2\frac{y^2}{2}|_0^x=2x-x^2=x(2-x)$$

Comment: wouldn't $-(1-y)^2$ also be right? Tried differentiating it and it result I got is 2(1−y)

Comment: the right solution is given by $$\int_{0}^x 2(1-y)dy=-x^2+2x$$

Comment: How did you get that $-x^2+2x$?